# Simulate Schmitt trigger on Simulink

Tags: matlab, schmitt-trigger, simulink

I'm trying to make the simplest circuit to see the Schmitt trigger behaviour on Simulink. I have the following circuit with the Schmitt trigger having the following options :
Low level input voltage : 0
High level input voltage : 4
Low level output voltage : 0
High level output voltage : 4
[image]

But as you can see, the output gives me something like 0.5 as an output. What is the problem here ?!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> *What is the problem here ?!*

The output of your Schmitt trigger is connected to ground <-- this is a show-stopper: -

[image]

> *But as you can see, the output gives me something like 0.5 as an
> output.*

If you fixed the short circuit problem then you need to fix your measurement. At the moment it is measuring the input to the Schmitt trigger and not the output.

When this is fixed consider the next potential problem...

Your input waveform appears to have a period of 5 seconds according to your plot. This means it has a frequency of 0.2 Hz. 1 nF has an impedance of 795 MΩ at 0.2 Hz therefore, the signal amplitude at the input to your Schmitt trigger is far, far too tiny to reach the Schmitt trigger thresholds of 0 volt and 4 volt.

Try using 1 MHz instead and use your voltmeter to ensure the waveform on the input to the Schmitt trigger meets the amplitude criteria I mentioned. Also try Schmitt trigger thresholds that are above 0 volts.